# Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument $True - Azure Az Powershell Module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I'm trying to update a property on my AD Application Registration in Azure.
Per the documentation, I can either use Update-AzADApplication or Set-AzADApplication.

I've tried both.  But all the combos below return the same error message:

```
 A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$True'.
```

**Update-AzADApplication Attempts**

```
PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId [my-app-guid] -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $True
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.

PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId [my-app-guid] -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $true
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.

PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -DisplayName widgets-app-AdApp -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $True
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.

PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -DisplayName widgets-app-AdApp -Oauth2RequirePostResponse True 
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.

PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -DisplayName widgets-app-AdAppp -Oauth2RequirePostResponse true
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'true'.

PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -DisplayName widgets-app-AdApp -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $true
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.
```

I also tried this:

```
PS C:\Users\me> $mytest = $True; 
PS C:\Users\me> $mytest
True
PS C:\Users\me> Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId [my-app-guid] -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $mytest
Update-AzADApplication: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.
PS C:\Users\me>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Oauth2RequirePostResponse` is a switch parameter so does not need a boolean value.

Because of this, PowerShell assumes the `$true` value you are attempting to pass is the next parameter.

Remove `$true` and it should work.

```
Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId [my-app-guid] -Oauth2RequirePostResponse
```

Comment: k. still not working.  Failing with "Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."  but i'll just post another question.  Thanks.